# N2CMS Publish button is missing

Tags: n2cms, n2

I am using the latest bits from Nuget, and after successfully installing and creating a root and start page node, when I edit the start page content I do not see the publish button?   In addition which could be unrelated, I'm unable to create new users getting a null object reference exception when I attempt to persist the user?

I'm using MongoDb as my persistence layer as well.

Comment: were you able to setup everything to work with mongodb?